# Unrolling Totals into Monthly Amounts for Actuals and Budget by CASE WHEN

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms, dynamics-gp

EDIT

```
             A    A    A    A    A    A    A (A or B) B   B    B    B
Acct  Desc  Jan  Feb  Mar  Apr  May  Jun  Jul  Aug  Sep  Oct  Nov  Dec  Ttl
100 | Retail|  0| 0  | 400|400 | 400 | 400|400| 1000|1k | 1k | 1k | 1k | 7k
101 | Repair|200| 0  | 0  |200 | 200 | 200|200| 1000|1k | 1k | 1k |  0 | 5k
```

I've been able to get almost what I need with the following.  It displays the the year-to-date actuals that have happened from Jan-Jul + any actuals that have happened in the current month (Aug) and shows the budgeted amounts for Sep-Dec.  I'd like to have a comparison of current month actuals vs current month budget and the greater to be displayed as the current month amount.  Ideally, this would be able to change if the current month actuals became larger down the road and to continue on as the months progress.

```
select Acct, ActDesc, sum(Jan) as January, sum(Feb) as February, sum(Mar) as 
March, sum(Apr) as April, sum(May) as May, sum(Jun) as June, sum(Jul) as 
July, sum(Aug) as August, sum(Sep) as September,
sum(Oct) as October, sum(Nov) as November, sum(Dec) as December, sum(Jan + 
Feb + Mar + Apr + May + Jun + Jul + Aug + Sep + Oct + Nov + [Dec]) as Total 
from (

select
a.ACTNUMST Acct
,g.ACTDESCR ActDesc
,sum(case
    when g.PERIODID <= datepart(month, sysdatetime()) and g.PERIODID = 1  
then g.DEBITAMT-g.CRDTAMNT else 0 end) Jan
,sum(case
    when g.PERIODID <= datepart(month, sysdatetime()) and g.PERIODID = 2 
then g.DEBITAMT-g.CRDTAMNT else 0 end) Feb
,sum(case
    when g.PERIODID <= datepart(month, sysdatetime()) and g.PERIODID = 3 
then g.DEBITAMT-g.CRDTAMNT else 0 end) Mar
,sum(case
    when g.PERIODID <= datepart(month, sysdatetime()) and g.PERIODID = 4 
then g.DEBITAMT-g.CRDTAMNT else 0 end) Apr
,sum(case
    when g.PERIODID <= datepart(month, sysdatetime()) and g.PERIODID = 5 
then g.DEBITAMT-g.CRDTAMNTelse 0 end) May
,sum(case
    when g.PERIODID <= datepart(month, sysdatetime()) and g.PERIODID = 6 
then g.DEBITAMT-g.CRDTAMNTelse 0 end) Jun
,sum(case
    when g.PERIODID <= datepart(month, sysdatetime()) and g.PERIODID = 7 
then g.DEBITAMT-g.CRDTAMNTelse 0 end) Jul
,sum(case
    when g.PERIODID <= datepart(month, sysdatetime()) and g.PERIODID = 8 
then g.DEBITAMT-g.CRDTAMNTelse 0 end) Aug
,sum(case
    when g.PERIODID <= datepart(month, sysdatetime()) and g.PERIODID = 9 
then g.DEBITAMT-g.CRDTAMNTelse 0 end) Sep
,sum(case
    when g.PERIODID <= datepart(month, sysdatetime()) and g.PERIODID = 10 
then g.DEBITAMT-g.CRDTAMNTelse 0 end) Oct
,sum(case
    when g.PERIODID <= datepart(month, sysdatetime()) and g.PERIODID = 11 
then g.DEBITAMT-g.CRDTAMNTelse 0 end) Nov
,sum(case
    when g.PERIODID <= datepart(month, sysdatetime()) and g.PERIODID = 12 
then g.DEBITAMT-g.CRDTAMNTelse 0 end) [Dec]

from GL111 g inner join   

GL100 d on g.ACTINDX = d.ACTINDX inner join 
GL105 as a on g.ACTINDX = a.ACTINDX

where (g.YEAR1 = 2017) and (g.PERIODID <= DATEPART(month, sysdatetime()))
group by a.ACTNUMST, g.ACTDESCR
UNION ALL

SELECT a.ACTNUMST Acct,
m.ACTDESCR ActDesc
,sum(case
 when b.PERIODID >  datepart(month, sysdatetime()) and b.PERIODID = 1  then b.BUDGETAMT else 0 end) Jan
,sum(case
 when b.PERIODID >  datepart(month, sysdatetime()) and b.PERIODID = 2 then b.BUDGETAMT else 0 end) Feb
,sum(case
when b.PERIODID >  datepart(month, sysdatetime()) and b.PERIODID = 3 then b.BUDGETAMT else 0 end) Mar
,sum(case
when b.PERIODID >  datepart(month, sysdatetime()) and b.PERIODID = 4 then b.BUDGETAMT else 0 end) Apr
,sum(case
when b.PERIODID >  datepart(month, sysdatetime()) and b.PERIODID = 5 then b.BUDGETAMT else 0 end) May
,sum(case
when b.PERIODID >  datepart(month, sysdatetime()) and b.PERIODID = 6 then b.BUDGETAMT else 0 end) Jun
,sum(case
when b.PERIODID >  datepart(month, sysdatetime()) and b.PERIODID = 7 then b.BUDGETAMT else 0 end) Jul
,sum(case
when b.PERIODID >  datepart(month, sysdatetime()) and b.PERIODID = 8 then b.BUDGETAMT else 0 end) Aug
,sum(case
when b.PERIODID >  datepart(month, sysdatetime()) and b.PERIODID = 9 then b.BUDGETAMT else 0 end) Sep
,sum(case
when b.PERIODID >  datepart(month, sysdatetime()) and b.PERIODID = 10 then b.BUDGETAMT else 0 end) Oct
,sum(case
when b.PERIODID >  datepart(month, sysdatetime()) and b.PERIODID = 11 then b.BUDGETAMT else 0 end) Nov
,sum(case
when b.PERIODID >  datepart(month, sysdatetime()) and b.PERIODID = 12 then b.BUDGETAMT else 0 end) [Dec]
                   FROM      GL201 AS b INNER JOIN
                                     GL105 AS a ON b.ACTINDX = a.ACTINDX inner join 
                                     GL100 AS m ON a.ACTINDX = m.ACTINDX
                   WHERE   (b.BUDGETID = '2017FORECAST')  and (b.PERIODID > DATEPART(month, sysdatetime()))
                   GROUP BY a.ACTNUMST, m.ACTDESCR

)  as derivedtbl_1                         
group by Acct, ActDesc
order by Acct
```

Comment: As @used_by_already is hinting at (I think), where are you expecting your actuals in the columns you provided? As a separate set of 12 columns? Another row? That requirement doesn't seem to be clear.

Comment: @Used_By_Already

Comment: @JacobH For example, the actuals should show Jan-July and then budget should appear Sep-Dec all in the same table. The part I'm struggling with currently is getting in Aug the comparison of current month actuals and current month budget and displaying the greater of the two. Since it's the beginning of Aug the budget is likely greater, but further on in the month the actuals could surpass it and be shown instead.

Answer (score 1):

Not being fully familiar with the tables and data model, all I am going to do is suggest that this snippet of logic:

```
g.PERIODID <= datepart(month, sysdatetime())
```

Appears to determine the breakpoint between actuals and forecast. So, incorporate this logic into the various case expressions you are currently using to align the data into months. This might look something like the following:

```
, SUM(CASE
        WHEN g.PERIODID <= datepart(month, sysdatetime()) and b.PERIODID = 1  THEN actual_amount
        WHEN g.PERIODID >  datepart(month, sysdatetime()) and b.PERIODID = 1  THEN b.BUDGETAMT
        ELSE 0 END) Jan
```

and repeat for each of the 12 columns. How you arrive at the "actual_amount" I have not attempted to provide.